# When Free shipping is available hide other shipping methods except Local pickup in WooCommerce 3.7

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Using *"[When Free shipping is available hide other shipping methods except Local pickup in WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338215/when-free-shipping-is-available-hide-other-shipping-methods-except-local-pickup/338219#338219)"* answer code, I would like to show Local pickup and free shipping when free shipping is available (hiding other shipping methods), but It does not work for me.

Where am I wrong?

I am using Wordpress Version 5.2.3 with Woocommerce Version 3.7.0…

Comment: You just forgot once this code is pasted and saved in functions.php file of your active theme, to refresh shipping methods as explained at the end of [the answer thread where you picked the code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/338219/79855)… This code still works perfectly on Woocommerce Version 3.7.x

Comment: Hi Loic,
you are right, my mistake I had another function in function.php that blocked your function. Your work works perfectly.